# Preforming a double ajax call in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Im Trying to Make A double Http requests , One after i get the result of the first 
but i seem to miss something :

```
getParkingSpots(date) {
 var gmt = this.getFuseauHoraire().subscribe(data=>{
   if(data=="GMT"){
     return this.http.get(url1+date+"GMT").map(res=>res);//this is the data i want never mind the urls
   }
   else{
      return this.http.get(url2+date).map(res=>res);//this is the data i want
   }
 })
```

}

```
this.parkpace.getParkingSpots(dd).subscribe(data=> {//here is where i use it
  this.ParkingSpaces = data; 
  console.log(data);
  console.log("dd="+dd);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getParkingSpots(date) {
  const gmtCall = this.http.get(url1+date+"GMT");
  const nonGmtCall = this.http.get(url2+date);

  return this.getFuseauHoraire().pipe(
    concatMap(data => data=="GMT" ? gmtCall : nonGmtCall)
  );
}
```

Comment: im still having an error :
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function
is the way im using the service by subscribe is correct ??

Comment: the error you're getting is not related to the code sample you provided. It's something with webpack configuration. Obviously, I can't provide any help in that regard since I don't have any details about your webpack config. It's also out of the scope of this question

Answer (score 0):

Use switchMap to start with one Observable and switch to another while keeping the stream alive:

```
getParkingSpots(date) {
 return this.getFuseauHoraire().pipe(switchMap(data=>{
   if(data=="GMT"){
     return this.http.get(url1+date+"GMT").pipe(map(res=>res));//this is the data i want never mind the urls
   }
   else{
      return this.http.get(url2+date).pipe(map(res=>res));//this is the data i want
   }
 }))
```

Comment: its seems that im having an error with the way i use the fuction  : Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: webpack_require.e is not a function is the way im using the service by subscribe is correct

Answer (score 0):

`webpack_require` is part of the generated bundle. You either have something going on with webpack, or imported a module incorrectly.

As far as your code sample is concerned, there is no issue that would cause this error to be thrown.